# Ubuntu 12.04 dvd/rw has stopped mounting and cannot gain access to dvd/rw

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd

I have followed a number of threads over the last 6-8 hours but I am unable to get my removable disk drive to mount (either automatically or via the terminal command line).

The processor is an AMD64 Athlon 3500+ and the DVD Drive is a TSSTCorp CD/DVDW TS-H552D HP06.

I have tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but because the drive doesnt mount on system boot, I cannot approach it from this angle either!

Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hardware issue to me. Namely sounds like your DVD drive has given up the ghost.  What I would recommend is putting a different one in your machine or using an external one.

Comment: It might be, but I took as he meant the DISC itself was removable, and not the actual drive... but I guess only he can clarify that.

Comment: ahh well, guess it could be taken either way, still this was a great answer......